# Matrices of "long"s in Java/COLT?

Tags: java, matrix, long-integer, colt

I'm very new to Java/COLT so apologies if this is a dumb question... But, is it possible to define (2d) matrices of type "long" using the cern.colt.matrix stuff? If so, how?! I can find an abstract class for "Object" and a concrete implementation for "double", but then I am stuck... Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question... it appears that it is not possible in the latest official version of COLT (1.2).

*However*, it *does* seem to be possible in the beta sourceforge project "Parallel COLT":

https://sourceforge.net/projects/parallelcolt/

I had noticed this project but ignored it, assuming it was just a parallelised version of COLT (which is interesting, but not what I wanted right now). But it turns out that it runs fine on regular hardware, and has a number of extensions and updates relative to COLT 1.2, including matrices of ints and longs... The documentation isn't quite up-to-date with the implementation, but is good enough.